# Android: importing Facebook SDK results in jar mismatch. How to avoid that?

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

I have a simple problem. Simple, but still a problem.

I've been trying to import the facebook sdk in my project and it gives me **jar mismatch**. I follow these steps

> Project Proprieties -> Android -> Add Facebook SDk (previously
>   imported)

Right after that i get a bunch of errors everywhere (i would put a picture but i need 10 reputation first...:( )

It seems like it behaves as if the appcompat library it's not there anymore.

So i tried to experiment a little, i removed the facebook sdk (the one i just added above) from my **testapp** and i went to my app `JavaBuildPath` and i added the single jar file `facebooksdk.jar`

It seemed ok, i wrote a simple code for loggin in (`facebook.authorize(...)`) but when i run it on an android device,this crashes and spits back `NoClassDefFound` hoping i don't notice.

My project also includes the `appcompat_v7` project, which is already there when i create the new project.

Now, i kind of understand that `appcompat` and `facebooksdk` generate my jar mismatch. If anyone knows a "safe" way to `import` the `facebook-sdk` that would allow me to integrate facebook to my app that would be just fantastic.

As you probably guessed, I'm not a android expert, this is my first time using StackOverflow and i hope i can solve my problem with your help.

EDIT:

Ok guys, i might have figured out a solution (nothing certain).

What i did was removing the android-support-v4.jar from the appcompat project (automatically generated when you create the app project). then simply add the facebooksdk from Proprierties ->android ->add.

by doing so i get no "jar mismatch" problem anymore and the app doesn't crash.

if someone can confirm that please, thanks.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post log cat error?

Comment: this is what i get when i add the facebooksdk.jar (single file) and launch the app

04-04 16:47:23.582: E/AndroidRuntime(6770): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.R$string

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove the `android-support-v4.jar` file from the **libs** folder from your project.As it comes with facebook sdk. It works for me as well !!!

Comment: i tried. i eliminate the android-support-v4.jar from the "libs" folder. then i added the "facebookSDK" project. still nothing, it gives me errors everywhere, like it's not recognizing appcompat

Comment: yes i did. eliminate file -> add facebook sdk project -> clean - > damn errors

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. i fixed it like this. you also can try this.

Delete the android-support-v4.jar from the your project library. And copy the android-support-v4.jar file from the Facebook SDK's libs folder and paste it in to your project libs folder.

And then refresh the your project and finally clean all projects after doing the above.

Comment: when i add android-support-v4 to my libs folder (copied from facebooksdk" it gives me jar mismatch and errors (like above, acting like appcompat didn't exist)

Comment: did you add it again?

Comment: yes, as soon as i add the supportv4 from facebooksdk the errors come back

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. What I did was copy the same `android-support-v4.jar` file (chose the one from Facebook SDK) to my `appcompat` libs folder **AND** to my `project` libs folder as well. That jar file needs to be the same throughout all the libraries you're using. Hope it works for you too!